# How would I load multiple values in to an equation?

Tags: python

If I have a set `x1 = [0, 0, 0, 1]` and `x2 =[1, 0, 0, 1]`, how would I iterate and print out an equation like

```
zscore = 1*w0 + w1*x1 + w2*x2
```

w's are constants

Printing out the x1 as a column x2 as column and score as column?

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to do (as right now it doesn't look like any z-score calculation I'm familiar with)? For instance, are you asking how to print `w1 * x1[0] + w1 * x1[1]...` or just calculate the values or do you want to change `x1` to `[0 * w1, 0 * w1, 0 * w1, 1 * w1]` and do you then want to print or just calculate those values?

Comment: how to out put zscore with each element in x1 and x2 I was doing logic tables and wanted to assign  zscore to each row : 1 row [0,0] 2nd row [0,1], third [1,0] then finally [1,1]   so at end i would have a column of zscore.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to calculate the zscore for each pair in x1 and x2 and print out the results in a column.

```
x1 = [0,0,0,1]
x2 = [1,0,0,1]
for x,y in zip(x1,x2):
  print(x1, x2, 1*w0 + w1*x + w2*y)
```

According to your comment, if the numbers in your list are strings, you can do this to convert them into ints.

```
x1 = map(int, x1)
```

You can use that to convert lists of any type to a list of ints (assuming the conversion is possible).

Comment: thanks Vaib but your statement tracedbacked error probably because i dont know how to tell machine my list  zip = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] (new list of numbers from my original question.) are numbers?